# It's a Slippery Slope

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, calculus

There has not been a challenge regarding slope fields, as a far as I can tell. So, I might as well make one.

## The challenge

Given:

- A [black box function `f`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/standard-definitions-of-terms-within-specifications/13706#13706) which takes two arguments, `x` and `y` (both real numbers) , and returns the value of the slope at point `(x,y)` (also a real number)
- A list of real numbers, `X`, representing the values along the `x` axis,
- Another list of real numbers, `Y`, representing the values along the `y` axis.
- A list of `(x,y)` pairs, `U`, which represents the inputs that `f` is undefined on. This argument can be removed if your language can detect errors.

Output:

- A rectangle with a length of the length `X`, and a height of the length of `Y`. At each combination of row `r` and column `c` in the rectangle, (starting from the bottom left corner), the character that is placed at that position will depend on the sign value of `f` evaluated at `x=c` and `y=r`:

  - If the value is positive, the character is `/`.
  - If the value is zero, the character is `-`.
  - If the value is negative, the character is `\`.
  - If `(x,y)` is not in the domain of `f` (a.k.a. a member of `U`), then the character is . `f` is guaranteed to not error on every combination of `x` within `X` and `y` within `Y` if `U` is utilized.

Since I am horrible at explaining things, here's an example:

Input:

```
f(x,y) = x / y
X=[-1,0,1]
Y=[-1,0,1] 
U=[[-1,0],[0,0],[1,0]]
```

Output:

```
\-/

/-\
```

- At `(0,0)` (the bottom left corner), the corresponding `X` and `Y` values are `-1` and `-1` (since `X[0] = -1` and `Y[0] = -1`). `f(-1,-1)=(-1)/(-1)=1`, thus `/` is used.
- At `(1,0)` (the bottom row, middle column): `X[1] = 0, Y[0] = -1`, `f(0,-1)=(0)/(-1)=0`, and `0` is zero (duh), so the character is `-`.
- At `(1,1)` (the center): `X[1] = 0, Y[1] = 0`. `[0,0]` is a member of `U`. Therefore, it corresponds to the  character. Or, if done without `U`: `0/0` is undefined, thus the character is .
- At `(2,2)` (the top left): `X[2] = 1, Y[2] = 1, f(1,1)=(1)/(1)=1`, which is positive. Therefore, it corresponds to the `/` character.
- Etc...

## Floating Point

Any value of `f` within the range `[-1e-9,1e-9]` should be considered to have a sign of `0`.

## Winning condition

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte count wins!

Comment: Are the inputs sorted?

Comment: @Giuseppe No. And unsorted `X` and `Y` will actually change the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
Ṛ⁹,2⁶v$Ṡ$e⁵$?¥þị“/ \-”Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlmPGnfqGD1q3Fam8nDnApXUR41bVewPLT287@Hu7kcNc/QVYnQfNcyN/P//f7SuoY6CgY6CYSwKE8KO1VGINoDSYH7sf/XD2/XVAQ)

Arguments: `Y`, `X`, `U`, `f`

`f` is a Python string containing Jelly code. **Be sure to quote it appropriately**, otherwise you may encounter errors.

Also, **`f` takes a pair `[x, y]` as its argument, not two arguments `x` and `y`**.

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation for those of us who have to constantly refer to the wiki?

Comment: @Zacharý sorry, no time to

Comment: Whenever you get the chance

Comment: [Explanation](https://tio.run/##dVPBSgMxEL3vV7xDwYtdUTx5EZEeFEURL4KX4E7baEwkmW3tzZ79A1Hw4icoFMGDfkn3R@pkV@2utGHZTTbz3rx5mVySMaPZbDp5KMaT1Y1i/DZoTSfPLSrGr63tz5evj@n7fXH3uIbzdnH3dIY2DpW2MNpepThVVxSwCeV7@TVZDgka4@vjb9rGUc7kceNdll8wnE3TtBn@@YJauGxznySeBtrlATx0ZdYAJQ@ykcoa8G3U0adklR9Bd@cxZUloRAG7zmaatbNb1b/OrQ4cIBXG5Nz3OpPFTc6JWITFI/LsdRFYMUUXItUJDcgHStC0dQGyYwLVsD96W1gUCxyowFEWUd2Ma2ejG2WuZQrjOFbal4UFupDCq8ow1NzHRopdZYzsKsZOqSKqXs7VGSiTi@qSr@tyLyS/fVBR/q12fg9BLFhGF1upkqZ7Fq5bzj2F3HDyHzPvx4g/02SyCspe2x5W4ubKf5T08TznoTShUX4V6@JBRreUVV95s6txJYtPPF6DfSdNUtZpaShnQWE2@wY) (May not be 100% correct)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @ngn*

```apl
{o←⍺⍺⋄'\-/ '[⊖⍉⍺∘.{0::4⋄2+×⍺o⍵}⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqfCDxqHcXCHW3qMfo6iuoRz/qmvaotxMk1DFDr9rAysoEKGekfXg6UCj/Ue/WWiCOrf3//9B6QwUDBUMFhWoDW6CQleHh7QZAlUBVh7eDlCmkKUCVcKnb2tqqc2kcWm@i/ah3s7mmgi5Y0hTEs8SUrUGSBQA) <sub>(with modified division, since basic APL 0÷0 is 1)</sub>

The black box function comes as left operand, `X` as left argument, and `Y` as right argument.

Comment: ideas: take x and y as ⍺ and ⍵, not just ⍵ (you can still have the ⍺⍺); in the inner dfn return 2+×⍺o⍵ on success and 4 on error and then do square bracket indexing on the whole matrix in order to save some quotes

Comment: @ngn Looks like it already does most of what you've mentioned?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer did you notice there's an inner { }?

Comment: @ngn problematic with complex results (2J1s)

Comment: @Uriel the problem says `f` "_returns the value of the slope at point (x,y) (also a real number)_"

Comment: @ngn, oh I see now. Thanks!

Comment: @Uriel You don't need `⍉` - just swap `⍺` and `⍵`. And another improvement: you can use `⎕` for the inputs and claim it's not a "function" (i.e. operator) but a "complete program": `o←⎕⋄'\-/ '[⊖⎕∘.{0::4⋄2+×⍺o⍵}⎕]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 109 bytes

```hs
z x=last$0:[x|abs x>1e-9]
(x#y)(%)u=reverse[[last$"\\-/"!!floor(1+signum(z$c%r)):[' '|elem(c,r)u]|c<-x]|r<-y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrPDoIgAIDxe0@B/yYsUTzmtCeoU0dkjRyVC9SBNnS8O20dvH377Xtz8xFSer8B20hu5phU1Dr@MMCeS4FP7ABttCKYoKXR4iu0EZT@x7BtcREGwVOOo4bl0fSvYVFwi7tEI1TRFKROSKFgl2m0MNfV2DKna7wyr3g/gAYoPl3vYFrm26wvA4gBpLgkeV4SFu2FYIEo7DOCXF/jnZn/AQ)

Fairly straightforward solution. Uses `signum` to index into a string for the right char if the point is defined.

EDIT: Thought of a way to shave off a byte

EDIT 2: Thanks @Laikoni for taking off another 4 bytes!

Comment: Taking `f` as third argument and as infix function saves another byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpND4IgAIDhe78CvyYsUTzmtFu3OnVE1shRufBjgA0d/522Dt3ePXtfXL@FlN5vwDaSaxOTilrH7xrYYynwge2gjVYEE7Q0SnyE0oLS35iCtKJh2@IiDIKHnCYFy73un@MywC3uEoWQGydzkmKAXabQwlxXY8ucqvHK/MD7ETRg4PPlBubFXI06jyAGkOKS5HlJWPQvBAtEYZ8R5Poa/5n5Lw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Save some more bytes by using `elem` instead of `notElem`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrPDoIgAIDxe0@B/yYsUTzmtCeoU0dkjRyVC9SBNnS8O20dvH377Xtz8xFSer8B20hu5phU1Dr@MMCeS4FP7ABttCKYoKXR4iu0EZT@x7BtcREGwVOOo4bl0fSvYVFwi7tEI1TRFKROSKFgl2m0MNfV2DKna7wyr3g/gAYoPl3vYFrm26wvA4gBpLgkeV4SFu2FYIEo7DOCXF/jnZn/AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>95</s> 92 bytes

```python
def f(F,X,Y,U):
 for y in Y[::-1]:print''.join('/ \-'[[x,y]in U or~cmp(0,F(x,y))]for x in X)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZUs9DsIgGN09xbcB5qMFRg7QGzRpgwzVSqyx0DQdYPHqCDq6vP@3peMRvMp5vjtwtMMBR@yZPoELOyRYPIxGay6t3vbFH4Q0z7B4Slq4cGJMxGTLpoewv2/rRgV2tGSM2fqP9T@w7OhrWq/zBKXSsjnHNiEYrpBLFChR2X9bvbBoalZIfPGna2FZ/gA)

---

Error handling version:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>135</s> <s>132</s> 125 bytes

```python
def f(F,X,Y):
 def g(x,y):
	try:return'-\/'[cmp(0,F(x,y))]
	except:return' '
 for y in Y[::-1]:print''.join(g(x,y)for x in X)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYwxDoMgGEZnOcW/AS1qtRsH8Awa62AVLE1FQmgCp6dq08Gl48v33meCeyy6jHEUEiSpWM0ayhFsOBHPwgqJs4Fb4d5W4/SW43aYDbmwap9phxLhB2HcTwGMQC4WAigNTct5WnTcWKUdxtlzUZp8jzfHb05NoySvfr6PPawDL7KTzwMD2@tJkLRkV3oAivY3dIj8@V8RPw)

Comment: You can save the same three bytes I saved for Erik by replacing `([x,y]in U)*' 'or'-\/'[cmp(0,F(x,y))` with `'/ \-'[[x,y]in U or~cmp(0,f(x,y))` :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
f,X,Y,U=input()
for y in Y[::-1]:print''.join('/ \-'[[x,y]in U or~cmp(0,f(x,y))]for x in X)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYuxDsIgGIR3n@I2IP5tqSOJj9GkDTJUTSPGAiE1gcVXx1adnO67y30hLzfvDqVM1NNA3dG68Fy42E0@IsM6DFqpqjUqROsWxuq7t46zBqeKaZ0om/XTwcfXZQ5c0sTXTQiz@Wnze1GKfozz@ToiEbICT9hD1lKgQSboqiVIQmv@@Fs2kr/8dGPe)

-3 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Looks like I [can't](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13708/41024) just [assume `f` to be already assigned to a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/41024).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70003/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-jonathan-allan).

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 142 bytes

```swift
func f(X:[Float],Y:[Float]){print(Y.reversed().flatMap{y in X.flatMap{let s=try?b($0,y);return s==nil ?" ":s!>0 ?"/":s!<0 ?"\\":"-"}+["\n"]})}
```

Prints as an array of characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```
Table["-"["/","\\"][[Sign[x~#~y]]]~Check~" ",{y,Reverse@#3},{x,#2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlNC4IwGIDv/YrxLjy9w1zHIISgjkZ6mzuYjRzlBzpDGfOvryK6PR91YSpVF0aXhU@VSTqj22YQ62Q03WiQHNv@c7O5U4Ttya9@m9ytzr1ujDj1@kZinxXXpxLAQEAICHkOUohU3xsxLXSZpZTLoVLlYwECaGe8qJfqBxXTrUM7IeVOBp7EMbE0CikPkFjGkUW4wQi5@@qfnfRv)

In the expression `"-"["/","\\"]`, part 0 is the head (`"-"`), part 1 is `"/"`, and part -1 (the last part) is `"\\"`, so if we try to take the `Sign[f]`-th part of it, we get the appropriate character depending on if `f` is positive, negative, or zero. If none of the above apply, or if evaluating the function causes an error, the `~Check~` will catch the error and return the `" "` character instead.

(It still prints out a bunch of error messages, which should be ignored since we get the right answer at the end.)

We do this for all `x` and `y` values.